# Select rows that contain the same values

Tags: mysql, database

I need to extract the pairs of storeID that contain the exact same movies, using this table as an small example

| storeID | movieID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |
| 2 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | d |

The result query should be storeID 1 and storeID 2 as they share the same movies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT storeID, GROUP_CONCAT(movieID ORDER BY movieID) movies
FROM tablename
GROUP BY storeID
```

returns all the movies of each store as a comma separated list.
Use it as a CTE and with a self join get the pairs of stores with the same movies:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT storeID, GROUP_CONCAT(movieID ORDER BY movieID) movies
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY storeID
)
SELECT c1.storeID storeID1, c2.storeID storeID2
FROM cte c1 INNER JOIN cte c2
ON c1.movies = c2.movies AND c1.storeID < c2.storeID
```

Comment: Imagine that 10 (or 100) storeID have the same movieID list... your output will be too long.

Comment: @Akina *I need to extract the pairs of storeID that contain the exact same movies* this is the requirement.

Comment: That's true. Maybe this variant is more suitable for OP really.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT storeID, GROUP_CONCAT(movieID ORDER BY movieID) movies
              FROM table 
              GROUP BY storeID )
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(storeID) 
FROM cte
GROUP BY movies
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```